# How to redirect an old domain name to a new domain name while keeping the old domain name visible in the address bar of the browser?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect an old domain to a new subdomain, while trying to keep the old domain visible in the address bar of a browser.

I used htaccess to do it and everything works except keeping the old domain visible in the address bar.

Another thing that is important is that folders in the url and GET variables need to be maintained.

I'm trying to do all this elegantly via htaccess, because I don't want to use an i-frame to accomplish this.

Here's the code I've been using so far. It works, except for maintaining the old domain name in the address bar of the browser.

My question is, how do I keep displaying the old domain name in the address bar of the browser after the redirect? I read somewhere that this could be done by what is called 'proxying content', but I might be wrong. Neither do I know how that works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

**Update**:

Okay so I got a step further. The following code works when I put the website files in a subdirectory of the root.

However there is still an issue with it. While it does redirect example.com to example.com/subdirectory it does not redirect example.com/index.php to example.com/subdirectory/index.php .

I'm still trying to figure out how to do it so that it works with all files, including index.php.

```
#Redirect  a domain to a subdirectory, while displaying only the domain and not the  subdirectory in the browser address bar.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory/ [nc,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory/ [nc,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

One more note. Since all elements in my website use relative paths, I had to set the HTML root to the subdirectory also in order to make things work, because due the rewriterule the  relative paths in the HTML of the website were looking at the wrong root directory for files. Namely they were linking to the actual root directory, instead of the subdirectory. I set the html root/base to the subdirectory as follows:

```
<head>
<base href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/subdirectory/" />
</head>
```

---

Update:

Okay so I got a step further. The following code works when I put the website files in a subdirectory of the root.

However there is still an issue with it. While it does redirect example.com to example.com/subdirectory it does not redirect example.com/index.php to example.com/subdirectory/index.php .

I'm still trying to figure out how to do it so that it works with all files, including index.php.

```
#Redirect  a domain to a subdirectory, while displaying only the domain and not the  subdirectory in the browser address bar.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory/ [nc,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory/ [nc,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

One more note. Since all elements in my website use relative paths, I had to set the HTML root to the subdirectory also in order to make things work, because due the rewriterule the  relative paths in the HTML of the website were looking at the wrong root directory for files. Namely they were linking to the actual root directory, instead of the subdirectory. I set the html root/base to the subdirectory as follows:

```
<head>
<base href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/subdirectory/" />
</head>
```

Comment: Is the content exactly the same in the subdomain as in the old domain?

Comment: are the domain and the subdomain on the same server?

Comment: @misplacedme : No, the content in the subdomain is different.

Comment: @miah : Yes, both the domain and subdomain are on the same server.

Comment: You need to capture the path you are redirecting to. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory/$1 [NC QSA L]  I feel like you shouldn't have to adjust the base in HTML because any relative path in the root directory should translate to the same spot in the subdirectory. It may have not worked earlier because the .htaccess file was pointing everything to the actual subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

If the domains in the rewrite rule do not match, then apache will rewrite in the address bar.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomain_directory/$1 [QSA L]
```

If it is not in a same directory, you could create a symlink in your domains directory that links to your subdomains directory, which should work.  You would need to allow `FollowSymlinks` or `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` if they are not already set.

Comment: You're right, the domains in the rewrite rule do not match.

Can you or anyone else post a code example using FollowSymlinks and/or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch that works? I've looked for it online, but haven't found a code example yet that exactly does what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you have ssh access, you would run `ln -s {/path/to/subdomain-directory} {link-name}` where link-name would be the file you reference in the rewriterule.  If you do not have shell access, then you'll need to ask your hosting company if they can set it up for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

My intention was to accomplish this by adding a script to the htaccess file in the root directory of domain.com.

Comment: apache doesn't allow you to directly access files outside of your root html directory, even if they are the same user.  So to get around this you can create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) inside of the root directory that points to the external directory.  Then you can redirect to this symlink in the apache file and it will resolve to the external directory.

Comment: Okay, so if I moved the website that is hosted on the subdomain to a folder in the root directery, then would it be possible to accomplish what I want? I.e. a redirect from domain-one.com to domain-two.com/somedirectory/ , while at the same time keeping to display domain-one.com in the browser's address bar. Furthermore while subdirectories and GET-variables in the url keep working?

Comment: You need to add the QSA flag, but it should work. (added it to the answer.)

Comment: It's not working for me so far, this is what I have now:

    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain-one.com`
    `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain-two.com/directory/$1 [QSA L]`

I get: 500 Internal Server Error when I add those two lines to htaccess

Comment: When the domain names don't match in the rewrite rule apache triggers a redirect in the address bar. It has to point to a directory/file for it to display that route/file will thought changing the address bar.  Can you post an updated version of the .htaccess file? (keep the original up as well)

Comment: I'll post an update in an answer so that I can format it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2:

This code seems to be working for me:

```
#Redirect a domain to a subdirectory, while displaying only the domain and not the subdirectory in the address bar of a browser
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

That piece of htaccess code does break html paths in the website's code, but this can be countered by redefining the html base path by adding an html base-tag in the header of the website like such:

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/" />
</head>
```

Furthermore you'll have to take extra care with paths/links in your website's Javascript code to get those to work aswell.

In regards to paths in PHP you'll need to use relative paths to keep the website's PHP code working after the redirect.

It took me two days to figure this all out with only 4 hours of sleep, because a lot of htaccess code that is available online simply does not work. Hopefully this will save some other people a lot of work, stress and frustration.

Good luck. :)